# Cannot set property 'translationsDictionary' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

I got the many similar questions but no one is related to this.

```
'use strict'
var module = angular.module('TranslationModule', []);

module.service('TranslationSevice', function (dataService, $location) {
    this.translationsDictionary;
    var getTranslationsDictionary = function () {

        return dataService('Translations?culture=' + $location.search().culture).get(function (data) {
            try {
                this.translationsDictionary = data;
            }
            catch (ex) {
                console.log('Error!', ex);
            }
        });
    }
    getTranslationsDictionary();
});
```

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` / context inside a callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
return dataService('Translations?culture=' + $location.search().culture).get(function (data) {
            try {
                this.translationsDictionary = data;
            }
            catch (ex) {
                console.log('Error!', ex);
            }
        }.bind(this);
```